# « Le fruit de » et « l'aboutissement de »

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, synonymes

Peut-on employer :

> Le fruit de la recherche était...

comme synonyme de :

> L'aboutissement de la recherche était...

indiquant les travaux (articles dans des revues scientifiques, participations aux congrès) basés sur cette recherche ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quand on parle du « fruit de la recherche » il n'y a pas nécessairement le sous-entendu que quelque chose en particulier était recherché. Au contraire dans « aboutissement de la recherche » on sous-entend quelque chose de plus ou moins attendu; il s'ensuit que les deux termes ne sont pas équivalents.

Comment: +1 Alors dans ce contexte, l'aboutissement est plus adéquat, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: L'aboutissement, par contre, peut laisser soupçonner une idée de conclusion finale, alors qu'un arbre peut bien porter plusieurs fruits.

Comment: @Dimitris Cela dépend de quoi on parle dans le domaine de la recherche; si on parle des résultats sur plusieurs années et que l'on en évalue le volume, alors il s'agit de  « fruit ». Si l'on parle d'un projet avec un but il s'agira le plus souvent de l'aboutissement.

Comment: @Montée Je pense dans le sens de la première idée mais pour la seconde je crois qu'il n'y a pas de parallèle à chercher dans le nombre : il faut voir le mot « récolte » dans le mot « fruit ».